# Symfony2 fetch categories and subcategories using self Join

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Hello guys i have one litle problem i want to fetch all my root categories and sub categories and list it in twig .

**My database table looks like this:**

```
+----+----------+------------------+--------+
| ID | Parent   |      Name        | Status |
+----+----- ----+------------------+--------+
| 1  |          | Electronics      |   1    |
| 2  |   1      | Camcorders       |   1    |
| 3  |   1      | Computers        |   1    |
| 4  |   1      | TV Audio         |   1    |
| 5  |          | Motors           |   1    |
| 6  |   5      | Cars & Trucks    |   1    |
| 7  |   5      | Motorcycles      |   1    |
| 8  |   5      | Boats            |   1    |
+----+----------+------------------+--------+
```

Root categories dont have parent and have null value, all sub categories contain ID from root category.

**The tree looks like this:**

```
|—Electronics 
   |—  Camcorders   
   |—  Computers
   |—  TV Audio     
|—Motors                 
   |—  Cars & Trucks
   |—  Motorcycles
   |—  Boats
```

> NOTE: I dont need nested set data (tree data) this tree is just example

I want to show all that in twig  like this drop down menu:

```
+---------------------+--------+
| Electroics          | Motors |
+---------------------+--------+
  | Camcorders |
  +------------+
  | Computers  |
  +------------+
  | TV Audio   |
  +------------+
```

**Repository method where i fetch all root categories:**

```
  public function getAllCategoriesByName()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT c FROM ISLabECommerceBundle:Category c WHERE c.parent IS NULL '
            )
            ->getResult();
    }
```

**Controller :**

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine');
$categories = $em->getRepository('ISLabECommerceBundle:Category')->getAllCategoriesByName();
```

**Twig:**

```
<ul>
{% for category in categories %}
    <li><a href='#'><span>{{ category.name }}</span></a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Now i need to use JOIN to show all subcategories for category Electronics but i dont know to do that. I have low expiriance with join, left/right join. Any1 can give me example how to fetch all root and show subcategories for any1 root category.

**Update:**

**Entity**

```
<?php

namespace ISLab\Bundle\ECommerceBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ecomerce_categories")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ISLab\Bundle\ECommerceBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="integer")
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @var category
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="category", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="category", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer")
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="page_title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $pageTitle;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="meta_keywords", type="text")
     */
    private $metaKeywords;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="meta_description", type="text")
     */
    private $metaDescription;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    private $description;
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_created", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateCreated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_modified", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateModified;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * ArrayCollection
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * To String
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param integer $image
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param integer $parent
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setParent($parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param integer $status
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Set pageTitle
     *
     * @param string $pageTitle
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setPageTitle($pageTitle)
    {
        $this->pageTitle = $pageTitle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pageTitle
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPageTitle()
    {
        return $this->pageTitle;
    }

    /**
     * Set metaKeywords
     *
     * @param string $metaKeywords
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setMetaKeywords($metaKeywords)
    {
        $this->metaKeywords = $metaKeywords;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get metaKeywords
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getMetaKeywords()
    {
        return $this->metaKeywords;
    }

    /**
     * Set metaDescription
     *
     * @param string $metaDescription
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setMetaDescription($metaDescription)
    {
        $this->metaDescription = $metaDescription;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get metaDescription
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getMetaDescription()
    {
        return $this->metaDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateCreated
     *
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setDateCreated()
    {
        $this->dateCreated = new \DateTime();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateCreated
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateCreated()
    {
        return $this->dateCreated;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateModified
     *
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setDateModified()
    {
        $this->dateModified =  new \DateTime();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateModified
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateModified()
    {
        return $this->dateModified;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us categories entity?

Comment: check now my new update

Comment: I want result fetching categories and subcategories just like on http://www.ebay.com

Comment: What about [Doctrine2 - nested set](https://github.com/cbsi/doctrine2-nestedset)?

Comment: no i dont need that nested set here. I already use doctrine extension and stfo budnle dor that.

Answer (score 2):

First of all modify your entity as follows

```
public function setChildren($children) { //this will be an array collection so please pay attention
  $this->children = $children;

  return $this;
}

public function getChildren() {
  return $this->children;
}
```

You should also change variable name as `children` will be an `ArrayCollection` so I suggest to change it in `childrens` (for code semantic is better)

Then you could simply iterate over children directly inside twig

```
<ul>
{% for category in categories %}
    <li><a href='#'><span>{{ category.name }}</span></a></li>
    <ul>
    {% for sub_category in category.children %}
        <li><a href='#'><span>{{ sub_category.name }}</span></a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Doctrine will do it for you as your entity is "linked" with itself by children-parent relationship. When you call `category.children` in twig the `getChildren()` method will be invoked.

That's all

Comment: Deam that doctrine. Again problem in the doctrine and its magic :) He is amazing he automatic invoke getChildren(). THanks man this work good

Comment: @Ikac: yes, ORM are very useful :)